# Comparing two ints and using the diffrence for a calculation

Tags: java, if-statement, int

I have set a personal score to a player in the game that I am making.
I want to update this score if the player wins, but the amount it raises or drops is depending on the difference in personal score.

```
public int editScore(int personalScore){

if(endOfGame().getResult().equals("win")){
```

now I want to get both players their personal score and  compare them to determine how much points will be assigned:

```
        if(this.getPersonalScore.compareTo(partner.getPersonalScore))
```

How will I make this work? I will need a return of the difference between the two.

Comment: Sounds like you need to return `personalScore - partnerScore`. Or `Math.abs(that)` if it doesn't matter which is bigger.

Comment: You're over thinking this. To get the difference between two numbers you _subtract_ them. As we know, subtraction is [not commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) - so the order of operations matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not that clear what you want to do, if it is comparing two ints, there is a function in the wrapper class Integer:

```
int compareResult = Integer.compare(this.getPersonalScore(), partner.getPersonalScore);
```

The compare function return value does not in any case correspond with the difference between the two values that you are comparing.
This is explained in the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)

Often people explain that compareTo() returns -1 for smaller and +1 for larger, but this is not true. The contract states that a value *smaller than 0* or *larger than 0* will be returned.

For the difference between both you'll have to rely on good old fashioned math.
In this case you could do something like this:

```
int difference = Math.abs(int1 - int2);
```

and add this after you got the winning player by determining that with the compare funcion.

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo` Simply looks at the numbers themselves and return 1 if the first is larger, -1 if the second is larger and 0 if they are equal: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compareTo(java.lang.Integer)

What you want to is to look at how different the numbers are, and add this to your personal score.

So you could do the following inside the player's class:

```
int difference = this.personalScore - partner.getPersonalScore(); // positive if your score is greater, else negative or 0 
editScore(this.personalScore + differece);
```

It's still a bit unclear as to what you want. But I'm assuming that the player has a `personalScore` `int`, (or `Integer`, both are fine, java deals with autoboxing), and a getter `getPersonalScore()`, which returns this value.

As a sidenote, your write `getPersonalScore`, but forgot to add brackets. I'm assuming it's a method call (because it starts with `get`), and these always have brackets at the end: `getPersonalScore()`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
int winner = Math.max(partner.getPersonalScore(), personalScore);
int loser = Math.min(partner.getPersonalScore(), personalScore);
int d = winner - loser;
```